# assign function to object attribute

Tags: javascript, object, attributes, nested-function

I'm building a draggable grid with grid-items generated out of the local storage. For the draggable grid I'm using the library [Muuri](https://github.com/haltu/muuri).

Therefore I generate out of all my elements with the class `.bookmark-container` a Muuri Object and assign some attributes. The attribute `dragSort` includes all of the container elements in form of an array, which allows to drag elements from one container to an other.

This is my js code. `gridObjects` is globally defined and the function `createbookmarkContainer` is called on `body.onload`.

```
function createBookmarkContainer() {

  var bookmarkContainers = Array.prototype.slice.call($('.bookmark-container'));

  gridObjects = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < bookmarkContainers.length; i++) {
    gridObjects[i] = new Muuri(bookmarkContainers[i], {
      dragEnabled: true,
      dragSort: function () {
        return gridObjects
      }
    });
  }
}
```

When I drag an item, it doesn't call my anonymous function within the dragSort attribute. However in my simplified [codepen example](https://codepen.io/iamrbn/pen/rYMbrg) it works.

Where is my fault? Is it because i call the anonymous function nested in an other function?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: FYI, you can use `$('.bookmark-container').get()` to convert the jQuery collection to an array of elements.

Comment: Or if you want to loop over a collection, use `$(".bookmark-container").each()`.

Comment: Nested functions work the same as other functions. Are you sure you're calling the function?

Comment: Are you calling the function after the DOM is ready?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer per-se but your code should run fine (as you can see in the running snippet below).
It seems that you are not calling the function correctly.

```js
function createBookmarkContainer() {

  var bookmarkContainers = Array.prototype.slice.call($('.bookmark-container'));

  gridObjects = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < bookmarkContainers.length; i++) {
    gridObjects[i] = new Muuri(bookmarkContainers[i], {
      dragEnabled: true,
      dragSort: function () {
        return gridObjects
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700');

body {
 background-color: #2C3135;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: "roboto";
}

h1 {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 40px 0px 0px 20px;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: 400;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 color: rgba(255,255,255, .8);
}

.bookmark-container {
 position: relative;
 //background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.02);
 margin: 20px 0;
}
.item {
 position: absolute;
 width: 250px;
 height: 60px;
 line-height: 60px;
 margin: 15px;
 z-index: 1;
}

.item-content {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #3E444D;
 text-align: center;
 border-radius: 5px;
   box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px 0px rgba(47,47,47,0.03);
 font-size: 12px;
 color: white;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.item.muuri-dragging,
.item.muuri-releasing {
 z-index: 2;
}
.item.muuri-hidden {
 z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/web-animations/2.3.1/web-animations.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/muuri/0.5.0/muuri.min.js"></script>

<body onload="createBookmarkContainer()">
<h1>SECTION 1</h1>
<div class="bookmark-container c1">
 <div class="item">
  <div class="item-content">1</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="item-content">2</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="item-content">3</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="item-content">4</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="item-content">5</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="item-content">6</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="item-content">7</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="item-content">8</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="item-content">9</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="item-content">10</div>
 </div>
</div>

<h1>SECTION 2</h1>
<div class="bookmark-container c2">
 <div class="item">
  <div class="item-content">1</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="item-content">2</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="item-content">3</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="item-content">4</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="item-content">5</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="item-content">6</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="item-content">7</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="item-content">8</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="item-content">9</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="item-content">10</div>
 </div>
</div>

<h1>SECTION 3</h1>
<div class="bookmark-container c3">
 <div class="item">
  <div class="item-content">1</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="item-content">2</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="item-content">3</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="item-content">4</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="item-content">5</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="item-content">6</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="item-content">7</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="item-content">8</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="item-content">9</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="item-content">10</div>
 </div>
</div>

<h1>SECTION 4</h1>
<div class="bookmark-container c3">
 <div class="item">
  <div class="item-content">1</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="item-content">2</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="item-content">3</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="item-content">4</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="item-content">5</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="item-content">6</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="item-content">7</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="item-content">8</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="item-content">9</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="item-content">10</div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
```